# Java backend POST request with body to a Spring endpoint that returns redirect to another URL

Tags: java, spring

So I am trying to do a POST request with body to an endpoint that returns a redirect to another URL with the status code of 302. Can I make this POST request from backend and retrieve the redirect URL as a String?

Thank you.

The endpoint I am calling looks like this and I need that redirect URL:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/something")
    public String doSomething(@RequestBody @NotNull final MultiValueMap<String, String> someMap) {
        doSomethinWithData();
        return "redirect:" + someUrl + "/abcd/" + "123457";
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrieve as a String where? If this is another Spring endpoint, it may be more convenient to just have another request mapping that has a `@PathVariable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the post request and then check for response code and return the Location Header.

```
if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 302) {
    String myRedirectUrl = myConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
    return myRedirectUrl ;
}
```

Comment: Will try and come back with a reply. Thank you!

Comment: No problem my man, I suggest ticking this as an answer that helped you so others can see it more easily ;)